# Inferior limit of output voltage in op-amp low-pass inverting amplifier circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, simulation

I'm simulating the low-pass inverting amplifier circuit using LTSpice:

[image]

I put a sine of amplitude 4 as input to see the behaviour of the op-amp in the non-linear zone. I was taught that the output voltage, in non-linear zone, can't exceed the positive supply voltage and can't be smaller than the negative supply voltage:

[image]
However, when running the simulation I get that the output, i.e. the voltage on the load resistance (V(3) on the simulation), gets smaller than the negative supply voltage (0):
[image]
How can this happen?

Comment: Try the LTspice universal op amp

Comment: That worked, thank you! The teacher had used this other model when simulating some other circuit and I mistakenly used it,

Comment: Glad to hear it. Your understanding of op-amps is correct you just got a bad spice model with regards to power supply inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For low input current reasons the Op Amp you selected is designed for +/-5V minimum due to the 4V FET biasing and the common mode rejection ratio or CMRR input range is 4V above the negative supply rail. (which you show as 0V)

Meanwhile, you are supplying +3V, 0V supply and driving it with 4Vp sine, so you can expect errors when you violate the specs. How the faults are simulated may not  be handled well, but you must be aware of the requirements for supply voltage and CM input range.